# From Programming Puzzles to Code Golf

Tags: code-golf, string, source-layout, whitespace

Your task is to write a program that outputs the *exact* string `Programming Puzzles` (trailing newline optional), but when all spaces, tabs, and newlines are removed it outputs `Code Golf` (trailing newline optional.)

Your byte count is the count of the first program, with spaces still there.

## Notes

- The spaces in `Code Golf` *and* `Programming Puzzles` will be removed as part of the removal, so plan accordingly.
- In encodings where 0x09, 0x0A and 0x20 aren't tabs, newlines or spaces respectively, those chars will be removed.
- If your code is

  ```
  42  $@ rw$
  @42
  ```

  then that must output `Programming Puzzles`. Also, in the same language,

  ```
  42$@rw$@42
  ```

  must output `Code Golf`.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins! Good luck!

Comment: will the space in `Code Golf` also be removed, what about the one in `Programming Puzzles`.

Comment: @ConnorLSW I assume so, see Mego's answer

Comment: In encodings where 0x09, 0x0A and 0x20 aren't tabs, newlines or spaces respectively, should the bytes or the chars be removed?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer the chars, not the bytes.

Comment: This will be impossible in at least [Whirl](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Whirl/)
 and [Whitespace](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Whitespace).

Comment: What are the close votes for?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 good question. I keep asking that but the comment gets removed...

Comment: The close votes are for the lack of inputs and outputs and restriction on the formatting of inputs and outputs. 100% if you had a section labeled "rules" with a bullet-pointed list of things you think were obvious about the challenge you'd have 0 close votes. It's all about presentation with CompSci folks, if we can think of a seemingly idiotic question to ask that may save us a byte or to, we will, try to counter that idiocy and you will be a great question writer.

Comment: I think this challenge resembles the quality of `polyglot` challenges. Though not entirely, of course. Awesome idea! +1

Comment: What about [non-breaking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)? In MathGolf, non-breaking space is the operator "discard everything but top-of-stack", which is quite useful in this challenge.

Comment: From Code Golf to Coding Challenges

Comment: I'd add a solution in Poetic, but such a solution would be at least 3111613151435231622325141268427653175133731762761752743751317 bytes long. (No kidding.)

Answer (score 71):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 50 bytes

```python
print["Code\40Golf","Programming Puzzles"][" ">""]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19QlJlXEq3knJ@SGmNi4J6fk6akoxRQlJ9elJibm5mXrhBQWlWVk1qsFButpKBkp6QU@/8/AA)

With all spaces removed:

```python
print["Code\40Golf","ProgrammingPuzzles"]["">""]
```

[Try that online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19QlJlXEq3knJ@SGmNi4J6fk6akoxRQlJ9elJibm5mXHlBaVZWTWqwUG62kZKekFPv/PwA)

Thanks to Stephen S for 3 bytes, and Erik the Outgolfer for 1

Comment: Darn, ninja'd! I was just about to click Post Answer! +1

Comment: I think you just broke my friend's brain. How does this even work?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro It's really simple. In the first case, `" ">""` returns `True`, since, lexicographically, a space is greater than the empty string. In the second case, `"">""` returns `False`, since nothing can be greater than itself. `True` and `False` are actually just `1` and `0` respectively, just in the `bool` datatype instead of `int` or `long`. In the first case, the spaces are preserved, so, the item at index 1, `"Programming Puzzles"`, is returned verbatim. In the second case, the spaces are gone, hence the `\x20` in the item at index 0 `"Code\x20Golf"` to preserve a space.

Comment: @Mego I don't really know Python, but if it is like JavaScript, can't `[" ">""]` simply be `[" "]`? Because empty string is false and non-empty string is true.

Comment: @StephenS Nope, because unlike JavaScript, Python doesn't have an obsession with implicit casting.

Comment: If find Python's lack of obsession disturbing.

Comment: @JanDvorak If it's any consolation, Python 2 has an obsession with comparisons. `[]>""`

Comment: Note that `bool` is a subclass of `int`. So `True` and `False` are actually equal to 1 and 0, just of type `bool` instead of `int`.

Comment: @Mego Your comment made me laugh out loud. Have a nice day sir. :)

Answer (score 59):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>48</s> 47 bytes

<sup>-1 byte thanks to Erik the Outgolfer</sup>

```python
print' 'and'Programming Puzzles'or'Code\40Golf'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19QlJlXoq6gnpiXoh5QlJ9elJibm5mXrhBQWlWVk1qsnl@k7pyfkhpjYuCen5Om/v8/AA)

```python
print''and'ProgrammingPuzzles'or'Code\40Golf'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#@19QlJlXoq6emJeiHlCUn16UmJubmZceUFpVlZNarJ5fpO6cn5IaY2Lgnp@Tpv7/PwA)

Comment: Aww, I was just about to improve my answer to this...

Answer (score 29):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
“Ñ1ɦ+£)G“½ċṭ6 Ỵ»Ṃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@/@oYc7hiYYnl2kfWqzpDuQc2nuk@@HOtWYKD3dvObT74c6m//8B)

#### How it works

As in the other Jelly answer, `Ñ1ɦ+£)G` and `½ċṭ6Ỵ` encode the strings **Programming Puzzles** and **Code Golf**. `“` begins a string literal and separates one string form another, while `»` selects the kind of literal (dictionary-based compression), so this yields

```
["Programming Puzzles", "Code Golf"]
```

`Ṃ` then takes the minimum, yielding **Code Golf**.

However, by adding a space between `½ċṭ6` and `Ỵ`, we get a completely different second string, and the literal evaluates to

```
["Programming Puzzles", "caird coinheringaahing"]
```

Since **caird coinheringaahing** is lexicographically larger than **Programming Puzzles**, `Ṃ` selects the first string instead.

Comment: Just did the same with `“½ċṭ6Ỵ“Ñ1ɦ +£)G»Ṁ`

Comment: To my knowledge neither of those characters can be saved using one byte, assuming well known encodings. in UTF-8 I get 34 bytes... Am I wrong?

Comment: @steffen Jelly uses a [custom code page](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page) that encodes each of the 256 characters it understands as a single byte.

Comment: @Dennis thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Where it all started.

Answer (score 26):

## C, <s>64</s> <s>62</s> <s>53</s> 52 bytes

```c
f(){puts(*" "?"Programming Puzzles":"Code\40Golf");}
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#@5@moVldUFpSrKGlpKBkrxRQlJ9elJibm5mXrhBQWlWVk1qsZKXknJ@SGmNi4J6fk6akaV37PzOvRCE3MTMPqBeoHygAAA)

Uses the fact that C strings end with a null character

Answer (score 22):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 15 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

```
”ƒËŠˆ”" "v”–±ÇÀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@/@oYe6xSYe7jy443QZkKikolQGpRw2TD2083H644f9/AA)

**Explanation**

```
”ƒËŠˆ”           # push "Code Golf"
      " "v       # for each character in the string " " do
          ”–±ÇÀ  # push "Programming Puzzles"
                 # implicitly output top of stack
```

Comment: ...I just don't get it. Does this use dictionary compression or something?

Comment: @LegionMammal978 I'm pretty sure it does.

Comment: @LegionMammal978: It does indeed use dictionary compression.

Comment: @Emigna Okay, because last I checked, neither of those strings could be fit into 4 bytes :p

Comment: To my knowledge some of those characters can be saved using one byte, assuming well known encodings. in UTF-8 I get 31 bytes... Am I wrong?

Comment: @steffen: 05AB1E uses a custom [code page](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md) (previously CP-1252) where each character is 1 byte.

Comment: How, exactly does the compression work? I tried looking at the language's source code, but couldn't figure it out. Also, how does one generate the compressed strings when golfing?

Comment: @Draco18s: Kevin has written a nice tutorial over at the [tips page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/47066) you can use to get a better idea of how to use it.

Answer (score 16):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
“½ċṭ6Ỵ»ḷ
“Ñ1ɦ+£)G»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ASYA2f//4oCcwr3Ei@G5rTbhu7TCu@G4twrigJzDkTHJpivCoylHwrv//w)

### Explanation

In the program as written, the first line is a helper function that's never run. The second line (the last in the program) is the main program, and is the compressed representation of the string `"Programming Puzzles"` (which is then printed implicitly).

If you remove the newline, the whole thing becomes one large program. `“½ċṭ6Ỵ»` is the compressed representation of the string `"Code Golf"`. `ḷ` evaluates but ignores its right hand argument, leaving the same value as before it ran; it can be used to evaluate functions for their side effects (something I've done before now), but it can also be used, as here, to effectively comment out code.

Interestingly, the actual logic here is shorter than the 05AB1E entry, but the code as a whole comes out longer because the string compressor is less good at compressing these particular strings.

Comment: This turns out to be valid.

Comment: To my knowledge some of those characters can be saved using one byte, assuming well known encodings. in UTF-8 I get 36 bytes... Am I wrong?

Comment: @steffen: Jelly uses its [own character encoding](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page), in which all of the 256 different characters it uses can be stored in a single byte. (The only reason it does this rather than using a pre-existing encoding is for readability (!); you could trivially write the program encoded in, say, codepage 437, and it would run in the Jelly interpreter, but it would typically be much harder to read.)

Answer (score 15):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 38 bytes

```
" ""Programming Puzzles""Dpef!Hpmg":(?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@6@koKQUUJSfXpSYm5uZl64QUFpVlZNarKTkUpCapuhRkJuuZKVh//8/AA) or [with spaces removed](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@6@kpBRQlJ9elJibm5mXrhBQWlWVk1qspORSkJqm6FGQm65kpWH//z8A)

**Explanation**

```
" "                    e# Push this string.
"Programming Puzzles"  e# Push "Programming Puzzles".
"Dpef!Hpmg":(          e# Push "Dpef!Hpmg" and decrement each char, giving "Code Golf".
?                      e# If the first string is true (non-empty) return the second string,
                       e#   else return the third.
```

Whether spaces are in the program or not determines if the first string is truthy or falsy.

Comment: Your code is sad `:(`

Comment: If you're willing to use unprintables, `"Bncd\x19Fnke":)` is happy code instead (replace `\x19`).

Answer (score 14):

## Javascript, <s>46</s> <s>43</s> 42 Bytes

```js
x=>" "?"Programming Puzzles":"Code\40Golf"
```

```js
console.log((x=>" "?"Programming Puzzles":"Code\40Golf")())
console.log((x=>""?"ProgrammingPuzzles":"Code\40Golf")())
```

Comment: You can replace the `\x20` in the first string with a space.

Comment: Beat me to it, nicely done.  Does this need a trailing `;`?

Comment: @ricdesi no, it dosen't.

Comment: @ricdesi since this is codegolf, if the program runs, it works. `;`s are sometimes not required in JavaScript.

Comment: You can replace `\x20` with `\40` to save a byte :-)

Answer (score 10):

### Haskell, 48 bytes

```
a _="Programming Puzzles";a4="Code\32Golf";f=a 4
a_="ProgrammingPuzzles";a4="Code\32Golf";f=a4
```

Defines function `f` which returns the corresponding string.

For reference, the old version is:

#### Haskell, 49/47 bytes

```
f""="Code\32Golf";f(_)="Programming Puzzles";f" "
```

with spaces removed

```
f""="Code\32Golf";f(_)="ProgrammingPuzzles";f""
```

Two simple pattern matches. `(_)` matches all patterns. You can improve the without-spaces version by one byte by defining the second pattern as `f" "=`/`f""=`, but this gives a "Pattern match is redundant" warning.

Alternative solution with the same byte count:

```
last$"Code\32Golf":["Programming Puzzles"|" ">""]
last$"Code\32Golf":["ProgrammingPuzzles"|"">""]
```

Answer (score 10):

### Wolfram language, 62 bytes

```
"Programming Puzzles"[ToExpression@"\"Code\\.20Golf\""][[0 1]]
```

The space in `[[0 1]]` is implicit multiplication, so this is equivalent to `[[0]]`. Without a space, `01` is just `1`. The 0th and 1st parts of this expression are the strings we want.

Another solution of questionable validity (44 bytes, 2 saved by Kelly Lowder):

```
"Programming Puzzles"["Code\.20Golf"][[0 1]]
```

The `\.20` gets replaced by a space immediately when typed into a Mathematica environment, so it's not clear if it gets removed along with the other spaces…

Comment: As soon as you paste (or type) this into Mathematica, (cloud based or not) the escape sequence, `\:0020` turns into a space, and thus would be removed, so I'm not sure this qualifies.  Also `\.20` is shorter.by two characters.  `"Programming Puzzles"["Code"<>FromCharacterCode@32<>"Golf"][[01]]` will work.

Comment: @KellyLowder, hmm, that's a good point. I've added another solution that should avoid that issue. (Thanks for the `\.20` suggestion — how did you find that? I thought I'd scoured the whole documentation…)

Comment: I found the `\.20` by making a typo. Seems to only work for two-digit character codes.  I don't think it's in the documentation.

Answer (score 7):

### Excel - 56 Bytes

```
=IF(""=" ","Code"&CHAR(32)&"Golf","Programming Puzzles")
```

Very similar to most of the other answers... nothing fancy here.

Answer (score 6):

## [Ohm](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), <s>33</s> 32 bytes

Uses CP437 encoding.

```
▀Bn¬i≈╣Ü╝Rb╡°╧S½uÇ▀
▀4>~H├MS░l╬δ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ohm#AT8AwP//4paAQm7CrGniiYjilaPDnOKVnVJi4pWhwrDiladTwr11w4filoAK4paAND5@SOKUnE1T4paRbOKVrM60//8) or [try without whitespace](https://tio.run/nexus/ohm#AT4Awf//4paAQm7CrGniiYjilaPDnOKVnVJi4pWhwrDiladTwr11w4filoDiloA0Pn5I4pScTVPilpFs4pWszrT//w)

#### Explanation

**With whitespace:**

```
▀Bn¬i≈╣Ü╝Rb╡°╧S½uÇ▀    Main wire

▀Bn¬i≈╣Ü╝Rb╡°╧S½uÇ▀    Push "Programming Puzzles" (compressed string)
                       Implicitly output the top stack element


▀4>~H├MS░l╬δ           Helper wire (never called)
```

**Without whitespace:**

```
▀Bn¬i≈╣Ü╝Rb╡°╧S½uÇ▀▀4>~H├MS░l╬δ    Main wire

▀Bn¬i≈╣Ü╝Rb╡°╧S½uÇ▀                Push "Programming Puzzles" (compressed string)
                   ▀4>~H├MS░l╬δ    Push "Code Golf" (compressed string)
                                   Implicitly output top stack element
```

Comment: I'm so glad I finally finished string compression!

Comment: @NickClifford The curious thing I noticed was that `Code Golf` got longer when compressed. I guess that's because of the capitals? Either way it's still shorter than writing it normally because I can't use a literal space here.

Comment: Yeah, Smaz is kind of weird like that.

Comment: FYI, feel free to ping me in chat if you have any questions or feature requests for Ohm.

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 29 bytes

With spaces:

```
`Co¸{S}Golf`r `PžgŸmÚÁ Puzz¤s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@5/gnH9oR3VwrXt@TlpCkUJCwKF56Yfm5x6edbhRIaC0qurQkuL//wE)

Without spaces:

```
`Co¸{S}Golf`r`PžgŸmÚÁPuzz¤s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@5/gnH9oR3VwrXt@TlpCUULAoXnph@bnHp51uDGgtKrq0JLi//8B)

---

This takes advantage of the fact that in Japt, a space closes a method call. With spaces, the code is roughly equivalent to this JavaScript code:

```
("Code"+(S)+"Golf").r(),"Programming Puzzles"
```

This is evaluated as JavaScript, and the result is sent to STDOUT. Since the last expression is `"Programming Puzzles"`, that string is printed.

Without spaces, the code is roughly equivalent to:

```
("Code"+(S)+"Golf").r("ProgrammingPuzzles")
```

(If you haven't figured it out by now, the `S` variable is a single space.) The `.r()` method on a string, if given one argument, removes all instances of that argument from the string. Since `"Code Golf"` does not contain `"ProgrammingPuzzles"`, it returns `"Code Golf"` unchanged, which is then sent to STDOUT.

Comment: I didn't even think of using replace. Nice one!

Comment: To my knowledge some of those characters can be saved using one byte, assuming well known encodings. in UTF-8 I get 36 bytes... Am I wrong?

Comment: @steffen Japt uses the ISO-8859-1 encoding, in which each char represents one byte. But some of the chars would be unprintable in this program, so I used the Windows-1252 encoding here (actually, it was autogenerated by [TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/japt))

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 44 bytes

```
" "Ṣ∧"Programming Puzzles"w|"Code"wṢw"Golf"w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@6@koPRw56JHHcuVAory04sSc3Mz89IVAkqrqnJSi5XKa5Sc81NSlcqBasqV3PNz0pTK////DwA)

#### Explanation

```
" "Ṣ                                           If " " = Ṣ (which is itself " ")
    ∧"Programming Puzzles"w                    Write "Programming Puzzles"
                           |                   Else
                            "Code"w            Write "Code"
                                   Ṣw          Write " "
                                     "Golf"w   Write "Golf"
```

Comment: Crossed out 44 is still 44 :( Edit in `&nbsp;` on either side to fix :)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino It's not crossed out, 44 is the length with spaces, and 42 without.

Comment: Oh. Whoops. Well, it's too similar so I couldn't tell without looking at the markdown by going into edit. Never mind :P

Answer (score 5):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 44 bytes

```
/"floG!"t"edoC"#
 /"selzzuP gnimmargorP"d&o@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6@vlJaT766oVKKUmpLvrKTMpaCvVJyaU1VVGqCQnpeZm5tYlJ5fFKCUopbv8P8/AA)

Without whitespace:

```
/"floG!"t"edoC"#/"selzzuPgnimmargorP"d&o@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6@vlJaT766oVKKUmpLvrKSsr1ScmlNVVRqQnpeZm5tYlJ5fFKCUopbv8P8/AA)

#### Explanation

In the first program, the two mirrors `/` redirect the instruction pointer onto the second line. `"selzzuP gnimmargorP"` pushes the required code points in revere order, `d` pushes the stack depth and `&o` prints that many bytes. `@` terminates the program.

Without the whitespace, the program is all on a single line. In that case, the instruction pointer can't move in Ordinal mode, so the `/` effectively become no-ops (technically, the IP simply doesn't move for one step, the same `/` gets executed again, and the IP reflects back to Cardinal mode). So if we drop those from the program, it looks like this:

```
"floG!"t"edoC"#"selzzuPgnimmargorP"d&o@
```

To include the space in `Code Golf`, we use an exclamation mark instead and decrement it with `t`. After we've got all the code points on the stack, `#` skips the next command, which is the entire second string. `d&o` then prints the stack again, and `@` terminates the program.

Comment: You must golf this (crossed out 44 is 44)

Answer (score 4):

## PHP, 44 Bytes

ternary operator

```
<?=" "?"Programming Puzzles":"Code\x20Golf";
```

### PHP, 51 Bytes

comment

```
<?=/** /"Code\x20Golf"/*/"Programming Puzzles"/**/;
```

### PHP, 57 Bytes

array switch

```
<?=["Code\x20Golf","Programming Puzzles"][(ord("
")/10)];
```

Answer (score 4):

## Common Lisp (SBCL), 52 bytes

```
(format`,t"~[Programming Puzzles~;Code~@TGolf~]"0 1)
```

Prints `Programming Puzzles`

```
(format`,t"~[ProgrammingPuzzles~;Code~@TGolf~]"01)
```

Prints `Code Golf`

Ungolfed:

```
(format t "~[Programming Puzzles~;Code Golf~]" 0 1)
```

Explaination:

The trick basically comes from how `#'format` works in Common Lisp.

In CL, most whitespace can be omitted provided that there is no ambiguity about where tokens start or end. The first trick was separating the `format` and `t` symbols. I had to unambiguously end the `format` symbol without changing how `t` was interpreted. Luckily, ` in CL ends the preceding token before it gets processed, and `,` cancels the effect of ` (` is used to implement templating, where the next expression following it gets "quoted", but any sub-expression prefixed with a `,` is evaluated and the result included in the template, so `, is nearly a no-op).

The third argument to `format` is the template string. `format` is similar to printf in C, but has much more powerful formatting directives and use ~ to indicate them instead of %. ~[ and ~] allow you to select between multiple options for printing, with ~; separating them. An additional argument is supplied to format- the numeric index of which one you want printed. In order to ensure that the " " in Code Golf survives, I used the tabulation directive ~T, which is used to insert whitespace, generally to align text into columns. ~@T is a variation which just inserts a given number of spaces, defaulting to 1.

Finally, there are two arguments to format- 0 and 1. Before whitespace is removed, the 0 is used by ~[~;~] to select "Programming Puzzles" and the extra format argument (the 1) is dropped (I'm not sure how standard dropping extra format arguments is, but this works on Steel Bank Common Lisp). After whitespace is removed, there is only one argument (01) which selects "Code Golf" instead.

Comment: +1, just one thing: "but any sub-expression prefixed with a `,` is evaluated and spliced in" Isn't `,@` necessary for splicing?

Comment: "spliced" is a poor term for that, admittedly. Technically, `,` evals the next expression and includes the result in the template, while `,@` assumes the expression will eval to a list and includes that list's contents in the template directly. Traditionally in the lisp community, `,@` is called "splicing", but I'm not sure that's the most obvious choice. I'll try to reword it a bit.

Answer (score 4):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), <s>43</s> 41 bytes

```perl
say" "?"Programming Puzzles":Code.$".Golf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7NCoJAFIX3PsVlEtqU1sKNEi0iWuYDDNSQNxVm7gw6o2j07Kb9QFDr853zHYOVjAZXI0TBar1KYKYJLlopQRnIknABrXYyg8oRtKUt4GzGCiz3Z88/beZDLToGbMvSSueVUKqkHFLX9xJrFu90hoHPgoOW12GeeCMMHzIG/3a6H501zsYs8bARctRPHlsgmBfldSFwyykMsylEpRuEtigt1kZc8LXI6b35fKid/SJiTpOH01/TLz88AA)

Uses the fact that `' '` is true in perl and `''` is false. The `$"` variable is set to a space by default.

Thanks to @NahuelFouilleul for removing two bytes.

Comment: maybe late but `"Code$\"Golf"` is shorter and `Code.$".Golf` too

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Yeah, I was pretty new when I wrote this answer. Thanks though!

Answer (score 3):

## C# <s>88</s> <s>81</s> <s>70</s> 63 bytes

```
Func<string>@a=()=>" "==""?"Code\x20Golf":"Programming Puzzles";
```

With whitespace stripped:

```
Func<string>@a=()=>""==""?"Code\x20Golf":"ProgrammingPuzzles";
```

Thanks to BrianJ for showing me how to have no space between a method return type and the method name, PeterTaylor for saving <s>7</s> 18 bytes, and Patrick Huizinga for saving 7 bytes.

Same method as everyone else really, <s>technically this could be considered invalid because the method doesn't specify a return type for the method, but there *has* to be whitespace between the return type and the method name.</s>

Comment: you can prefix the function name with an `@`, so then you have `void@a...` and avoid the "no return type" compilation error (also adds bytes, though :( )

Comment: `.Length<1` saves one byte; `\u0020` saves six if I've counted correctly; and  you can make a valid answer (and save a few bytes at the same time) by submitting a lambda instead of a top level function. `Func<string>a=()=>...`

Comment: @BrianJ Hmm, didn't know that, wonder why that works from a compiler view-point. Anyway, it may lose bytes but it also technically makes this answer not non-competing, so it's worth it. Thanks!

Comment: @Mayube the `@` is primarily used if you need to use a reserved word as a variable name (the equivalent is surrounding with `[]` in VB.NET (and MS SQL Server)).

Comment: @PeterTaylor wouldn't changing it to a func lambda require returning the string, which would need a space after `return`, thanks for the tip on Length and the space though

Comment: Yes, it requires returning the string; but if you use `=>` instead of `return` you don't need any spaces. (And even if you use `return`, you can `return(...)`).

Comment: But Brian's tip combines with mine if you change the header to say "C# version 6": `string@a()=>...`

Comment: No, `string@a()=>" ".Length<1?"Code\u0020Golf":"Programming Puzzles";` is a full-fledged method definition in C# from version 6.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Tried it in VS2015 with C#6 and it said it's only available in C#7, if you wanna post it as a separate answer for C#7 go ahead, my VS isn't setup for C#7

Comment: Huh. According to [the documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6) it's available from C# 6 in VS 2015. I'm not going to have access to a computer with any VS until Tuesday.

Comment: Can anyone explain to me why `" ".Length<1` is used instead of `" "==""`?

Comment: Also, `\u0020` can be replaced with `\x20`.

Answer (score 3):

## R, 50 bytes

I think this is the same as [this Javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117953), and basically the same idea as all the others.

```
`if`(' '=='','Code\x20Golf','Programming Puzzles')
```

Comment: [49 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PyEzLUGjINNGQddQR905PyU1psLIwD0/J01dRz2gKD@9KDE3NzMvXSGgtKoqJ7VYXfP/fwA "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 37 bytes

```
?" ""Programming Puzzles""Code\40Golf
```

[Try it here.](//pyth.herokuapp.com?code=?%22+%22%22Programming+Puzzles%22%22Code%5C40Golf)

```
?"""ProgrammingPuzzles""Code\40Golf
```

[Try it here.](//pyth.herokuapp.com?code=?%22%22%22ProgrammingPuzzles%22%22Code%5C40Golf)

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>47</s> 45 bytes

```
! v"floG!"1-"edoC"!
o<>"selzzuP gnimmargorP">
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@6@oUKaUlpPvrqhkqKuUmpLvrKTIlW9jp1ScmlNVVRqgkJ6XmZubWJSeXxSgZPf/PwA)

*Thanks to [randomra](/u/7311) for -2 (clever two `!`s so that I can use only one `>o<`.)*

The code shouts "Flog! Flog! Flog!" and resembes a fish.

Answer (score 3):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 50

```
[pq]sm[Programming Puzzles]dZ19=m[Code]n32P[Golf]p
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#S0mOT85PSbVV@h9dUBhbnBsdUJSfXpSYm5uZl64QUFpVlZNaHJsSZWhpmxvtDFQYm2dsFBDtnp@TFlvwX4krNTkjX0FJJQViipJCjUJKMkywGiqqr6@gXwuR@g8A).

`[ ]` defines a string - `Z` measures its length.  If the length is 19 then it contains a space and the macro stored in the m register is called, which prints `Programming Puzzles` and quits.  Otherwise `Code Golf` is printed.

Comment: Could you link to the dc interpreter / docs / github?

Comment: @programmer5000 Just choose dc on TIO, then click the language name.

Comment: @Dennis thanks, I didn't even know that TIO does that!

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 42 bytes

With whitespace

```
\"floG"48*"edoC"
/>o<"Programming Puzzles"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@x@jlJaT765kYqGllJqS76zEpW@Xb6MUUJSfXpSYm5uZl64QUFpVlZNarPT/PwA)

Without whitespace

```
\"floG"48*"edoC"/>o<"ProgrammingPuzzles"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/fish#@x@jlJaT765kYqGllJqS76ykb5dvoxRQlJ9elJibm5mXHlBaVZWTWqz0/z8A)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>74</s> <s>50</s> 48 bytes

```Java
()=>" "==""?"Code\040Golf":"Programming Puzzles"
```

Comment: @NonlinearFruit you're right, I've changed that one to be **non-competent**

Comment: I don't think printing is a requirement, so you could just return the string. I haven't tested it but the `==` operator should also work, `()=>""==""?"Code\u00A0Golf":"Programming Puzzles"`

Comment: `\u00A0` -> `\040` for a 2 byte savings.

Answer (score 3):

## [Befunge](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Befunge), 47 bytes

```
# <"floG"84*"edoC">:#,_@#" Programming Puzzles"
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT/3/X1nBRiktJ99dycJESyk1Jd9Zyc5KWSfeQVlJIaAoP70oMTc3My9dIaC0qiontVjp/38A)

Without spaces it skip the first < and prints Code Golf instead

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>₄₅</s> <s>₄₁</s> 39 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous lambda. Takes dummy argument.

```apl
{'Programming Puzzles'
⊢4⌽9↑'GolfCode'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24Rq9YCi/PSixNzczLx0hYDSqqqc1GJ1rkddi0we9ey1fNQ2Ud09PyfNOT8lVb0WpKV3DQA)

This function is a so called "dfn" which terminates with and returns the first non-assignment, i.e. `Programming Puzzles`.

Removing all whitespace gives:

```apl
{'ProgrammingPuzzles'⊢4⌽9↑'GolfCode'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24Rq9YCi/PSixNzczLx0hYDSqqqc1GL1R12LTB717LV81DZR3T0/J805PyVVvRako3cNAA)

This takes the last nine characters of `GolfCode` thus padding with a trailing space, then cyclically rotates that 4 steps to the left. `⊢` ignores the text on its left and returns the text on its right.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),  <s>**72**</s> **68 bytes**

Had output backwards at first, thanks Draco18s, then saved 4 bytes, thanks Jo King

```
a=0;ab="Programming";a
b="Code";ad="Puzzles";a
d="Golf";print(ab,ad)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9HWwDoxyVYpoCg/vSgxNzczL13JOpELKOKcn5IKZKYA5UqrqnJSi0HiQJ57fk6aknVBUWZeiUZikk5iiub//wA)

Comment: I think you have the outputs backwards.

Comment: Whoops lol, thanks. Fixed it

Comment: You can reuse the `a` to get [68 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9HWwDoxyVYpoCg/vSgxNzczL13JOpELKOKcn5IKZKYA5UqrqnJSi0HiQJ57fk6aknVBUWZeiUZikk5iiub//wA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 32 bytes

```
" "?`PžgŸmÚÁ Puzz¤s`:`Co¸{S}Golf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@6@koGSfEHBoXvqh@bmHZx1uVAgorao6tKQ4wSrBOf/QjurgWvf8nLT//wE)

Comment: Heh, I was just about to post the same thing :-)

Comment: Actually, [there is a shorter way...](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/117973/42545)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 56 bytes

```powershell
('Programming Puzzles',('Code'+[char]32+'Golf'))[!(' ')]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@6@hHlCUn16UmJubmZeuEFBaVZWTWqyuo6HunJ@Sqq4dnZyRWBRrbKSt7p6fk6auqRmtqKGuoK4Z@///17x83eTE5IxUAA)

Pretty basic I would say, but it gets the job done

Answer (score 2):

**PowerShell, 54 bytes**

```
"$((('Programming','Puzzles'),('Code','Golf'))[!' '])"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@6@koqGhoR5QlJ9elJibm5mXrq6jHlBaVZWTWqyuqaOh7pyfkgoUcs/PSVPX1IxWVFdQj9VU@v8fAA)

Without spaces

```
"$((('Programming','Puzzles'),('Code','Golf'))[!''])"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#@6@koqGhoR5QlJ9elJibm5mXrq6jHlBaVZWTWqyuqaOh7pyfkgoUcs/PSVPX1IxWVFeP1VT6/x8A)

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, <s>96</s> <s>82</s> <s>81</s> 67 bytes

```sql
print+iif(len(' x')=2,'Programming Puzzles','Code'+char(32)+'Golf')
```

[**Try it online**](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/686966) | [**Without spaces**](https://data.stackexchange.com/codegolf/query/686967)

Old version (96 bytes):

```sql
select(case'x'when(replace(' ',' ','x'))then'Programming Puzzles'else'Code'+nchar(32)+'Golf'end)
```

Comment: Nice work, you can get to 67 by losing the outer parens and changing the condition to `iif(len(' x')=2`

Comment: @BradC Close, but the outer paren prevents needing a space after `print`. I used a `+` instead and it worked.

Comment: Must've pasted and counted the wrong one. And I didn't know either, but the plus was the first character I tried and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>39</s> 37 bytes

*Thanks to [@Sanchises](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32352/sanchises) for removing 2 bytes*.

```
'Dpef!Hpmg'qc%
'Programming puzzles'&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X92lIDVN0aMgN129MFmVSz2gKD@9KDE3NzMvXaGgtKoqJ7VYXe3/fwA)

### Explanation

#### With spaces

`'Dpef!Hpmg'` pushes this string.

`q` substracts `1` from each code point, and `c` converts back to characters. This produces the string `'Code Golf'`.

`%` is the comment symbol. The rest of the line (which is empty) is ignored.

`'Programming puzzles'` pushes this string.

`&` specifies that the display function, which is implicitly called at the end of the program, must only print the top of the stack (instead of the whole stack). So the second string is printed.

#### Without spaces

`'Dpef!Hpmg'` pushes this string.

`q` substracts `1` from each code point, and `c` converts back to characters. This produces the string `'Code Golf'`.

`%` is the comment symbol. The rest of the line (that is, the rest of the code) is ignored.

At the end of the program the implicit display function is called, which prints the string.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 42 bytes

Simple comment abuse. (Hm, seems to confuse the syntax coloring too.)

```hs
{-- }"Code\SPGolf"--}"Programming Puzzles"
```

- With the spaces `{-- }"Code\SPGolf"--}` is a bracketed comment. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfm5iZZ1tQWhJcUqSiEPO/WldXoVbJOT8lNSY4wD0/J01JV7dWKaAoP70oMTc3My9dIaC0qiontVjp//9/yWk5ienF/3UjnAMCAA)
- Without the spaces `{--}` is a bracketed comment and `--}"ProgrammingPuzzles"` an end of line comment. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfmfm5iZZ1tQWhJcUqSiEPO/Wle3Vsk5PyU1JjjAPT8nTQnEDyjKTy9KzM3NzEsPKK2qykktVvr//19yWk5ievF/3QjngAAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 47 bytes

```
`Dpef!Hpmg `KtkL9=?";
\
c`Programming Puzzles`"
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/z/BpSA1TdGjIDddIcG7JNvH0tZeyZorhis5IaAoP70oMTc3My9dIaC0qiontThB6f9/AA)**

In its initial form, the top line adds the string "Code Golf" to stack, but with each character incremented, and a trailing space. It then decrements each character and checks if the length is 9 - however, as there is a trailing space, the length is 10, so the conditional is not entered. Therefore the top line is essential a no-op. The third line then prints "Programming Puzzles".

After modification, the program looks like this:

```
`Dpef!Hpmg`KtkL9=?";\c`Programming Puzzles`"
```

The `\` starts a comment therefore the only relevant code is the first half, which gets the string "Code Golf", checks its length (which is now correctly 9 as the space has been removed), and then prints it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 62 bytes

Lambda returning a string.

```
{" ".ifEmpty{"Code\u0020Golf"}.ifBlank{"Programming Puzzles"}}
```

1.3 introduced `ifEmpty` and `ifBlank` which each take a lambda and return its result if the receiving string is empty or contains only whitespace. If the condition fails, the receiving string is passed on instead.

So, if the spaces are removed, then the `ifEmpty` check passes and the `ifBlank` check fails. The reverse is true if the spaces are left.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYyxCsIwEED3fsVxUzIowVHQQRHXgqtLwF4JvVxKTAQb8u0xvvXx3hISO2kfy0BHUBp2Z3ik6GSGUysIuHd082v6FryG1/TMxhzMPTBh7ebCVpaCYwxztN7/qzFvG09vrLVRFvDWSb@WATpr/yZFSuuhth8)

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 34 bytes

```
╕│Çÿgolf]ûq¶$╦ÿming+û£q$╦α ?;;δ♥$u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///R1KmPpjQdbj@8H8SPPby78NA2lUdTlx3en5uZl659ePehxYUg/rmNCvbW1ue2PJq5VKX0/38A)

### Explanation

The code contains only one single space. With it, the stack contains `[['code', 'golf'], ['programming', 'puzzles'], ' ']` when the `?` is reached, otherwise it just contains the two lists. The `?`rotates the top three elements, and implicitly pushes a 0 to the stack when only two elements are on the stack. This means that the order of the elements is different after the `?` depending on if the space is present. It could be shorter by using the non-breaking space character, which is the "discard everything but TOS" operator, but I don't know if that is allowed.

```
╕│Çÿgolf]                                   Push ['code', 'golf']
         ûq¶$╦ÿming+û£q$╦α                  Push ['programming', 'puzzles']
                           ?                Push a space and rotate top 3 stack elements
                            ;;              Discard top two elements
                              δ             Capitalize string
                               ♥$u          Join with spaces
```

Answer (score 2):

## SmileBASIC, 49 bytes

```
TABSTEP=5?"Code","Golf"'
CLS?"Programming Puzzles
```

At first I was afraid I'd need to use `CHR$(32)` to for the space in "Code Golf". Fortunately, I can save exactly 0 characters using commas and TABSTEP.

Answer (score 2):

## bash, 51 bytes

```
(echo Programming Puzzles||dd<<<$'Code\40Golf')2>&-
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/XyM1OSNfIaAoP70oMTc3My9dIaC0qiontbimJiXFxsZGRd05PyU1xsTAPT8nTV3TyE5N9/9/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Befunge-98 (FBBI)](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 46 bytes

```
"floG edoCselzzuP gnimmargorP"f3+40# $j$k$8k,@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/XyktJ99dITUl37k4NaeqqjRAIT0vMzc3sSg9vyhAKc1Y28RAWUElSyVbxSJbx@H/fwA)

## Explanation:

```
"floG edoCselzzuP gnimmargorP" ¤ Put "Code Golf" and "Programming Puzzles" into
                                 the stack, character by character, 
                                 so that "Programming Puzzles" is on top of the stack.
f3+40                          ¤ Push 18, then 4, then 0 to the stack.
     # $                       ¤ With space: Jump over the whitespace and pop the 0.
        j$k$8                    Jump over the 4 next instructions.
             k,@                 Print the 18 top chars from the stack and exit.
```

---

```
     #$                        ¤ Without space: Jump over the `$` instruction,
       j                         Jump over the next 0 instructions.
        $                        Pop 4 from the stack.
         k$                      Pop the top 18 chars from the stack.
           8k,@                  Print out the 8 top chars from the stack and exit.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 62 bytes

```
System.write(" ".count>0?"Programming Puzzles":"Code\x20Golf")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9Kzfv/P7iyuCQ1V6@8KLMkVUNJQUkvOb80r8TOwF4poCg/vSgxNzczL10hoLSqKie1WMlKyTk/JTWmwsjAPT8nTUnz/38A)

### Explanation

```
System.write(                                                ) // Output
             " ".count>0                                       // Whether the length of this string is larger than 0
                        ?"Programming Puzzles"                 // If true, output "Programming Puzzles"
                                              :"Code\x20Golf"  // Otherwise, output "Code Golf"
```

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 71 bytes

```
System.write(Num.fromString("0 0")?"Code\x20Golf":"Programming Puzzles")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9Kzfv/P7iyuCQ1V6@8KLMkVcOvNFcvrSg/N7ikKDMvXUPJwEBJ017JOT8lNabCyMA9PydNyUopoCg/vSgxNxeoQiGgtKoqJ7VYSfP/fwA)

### Explanation

```
System.write(                                                          ) // Output
             Num.fromString("0 0")                                       // Whether converting to a single number is successful
                                                                         // If this isn't successful, it outputs null, which is a false value.
                                  ?"Code\x20Golf"                        // If this is successful, output "Code Golf"
                                                 :"Programming Puzzles"  // Otherwise, output "Programming Puzzles"
```

Answer (score 2):

## c, 73 bytes

[With whitespace](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQ0m1OCZPSSexJD9TQ0lXwVBJ017JOT8lNabCyMA9PydNyUopoCg/vSgxNzczL10hoLSqKie1WEnTuvb/fwA):

```
main(){printf("%s\n",atoi("- 1")?"Code\x20Golf":"Programming Puzzles");}
```

[Without whitespace](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z83MTNPQ7O6oCgzryRNQ0m1OCZPSSexJD9TQ0nXUEnTXsk5PyU1psLIwD0/J03JSimgKD@9KDE3NzMvXSGgtKoqJ7VYSdO69v9/AA):

```
main(){printf("%s\n",atoi("-1")?"Code\x20Golf":"Programming Puzzles");}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 45 bytes

```sh
\ ;<<<Programming\ Puzzles||<<<Code$'\40'Golf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P8/RsHaxsYmoCg/vSgxNzczLz1GIaC0qiontbimBijhnJ@SqqIeY2Kg7p6fk/b/PwA)

With spaces:

- `\` : execute the command  , (which doesn't exist so does nothing)
- `;`: then
- `<<<Programming\ Puzzles`: print `Programming Puzzles`
- `||` if that fails (which is never does, because printing is always successful):

  - `<<<Code$'\40'Golf`: print `Code Golf` (this doesn't get executed)

Without spaces:

- `\;`: execute the command `;` (which doesn't exist so does nothing with its input)
- `<<<Programming\Puzzles`: and send `;` the input `ProgrammingPuzzles` (which it discards, since it doesn't do anything)
- `||` if that fails (which it always does, since `;` is not a defined command):

  - `<<<Code$'\40'Golf`: print `Code Golf` (`$'\40'` is a space, written with an octal escape)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 20 bytes

```
` `[`↔ḃ ₄∩`|`¬꘍»₆`½Ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%20%60%5B%60%E2%86%94%E1%B8%83%20%E2%82%84%E2%88%A9%60%7C%60%C2%AC%EA%98%8D%C2%BB%E2%82%86%60%C2%BD%E1%B9%84&inputs=&header=&footer=)  and
[TryitOnline!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%60%5B%60%E2%86%94%E1%B8%83%E2%82%84%E2%88%A9%60%7C%60%C2%AC%EA%98%8D%C2%BB%E2%82%86%60%C2%BD%E1%B9%84&inputs=&header=&footer=)

### How it works

- `` ` ` `` is a string with one space, a truthy value. When spaces are removed, it becomes the empty string ``` `` ```, which is falsy.
- `[...|...]` is an conditional statement. If the top of the stack is truthy, the first part is executed, otherwise the second part.

  - If true (spaces are not removed): `` `↔ḃ ₄∩` ``, the compressed string `` `Programming Puzzles` ``, is pushed and output
  - Otherwise: `` `¬꘍»₆` ``, the compressed string `` `CodeGolf` ``, is pushed. `½` splits it into the list `` ⟨`Code`|`Golf`⟩ ``, which is then joined by spaces with `Ṅ` and implicitly printed.

---

#### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 21 bytes, for the new site name

Additionally, here is a 21-byte solution for the new site name - Code Golf and Coding Challenges:

```
` `[`¬꘍ »₆`|`⟩₆,→ṗ`⌐Ṅ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%20%60%5B%60%C2%AC%EA%98%8D%20%C2%BB%E2%82%86%60%7C%60%E2%9F%A9%E2%82%86%2C%E2%86%92%E1%B9%97%60%E2%8C%90%E1%B9%84&inputs=&header=&footer=) and [TryitOnline!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%60%60%5B%60%C2%AC%EA%98%8D%C2%BB%E2%82%86%60%7C%60%E2%9F%A9%E2%82%86%2C%E2%86%92%E1%B9%97%60%E2%8C%90%E1%B9%84&inputs=&header=&footer=)

It works similarly, using `⌐Ṅ` to replace the comma in compressed `Coding,Challenges` with a space.

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 38 bytes

```
" ""Programming Puzzles""Code\sGolf"if
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/golfscript#@6@koKQUUJSfXpSYm5uZl64QUFpVlZNarKTknJ@SGlPsnp@TppSZ9v8/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 76 bytes

```
" "0`#v_"floG"84*"edoC",,,,,,,,,@
,,,,,@>"selzzuP gnimmargorP",,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#@6@koGSQoFwWr5SWk@@uZGGipZSaku@spAMDDlwQyk6pODWnqqo0QCE9LzM3N7EoPb8oAKEMDP7/BwA)

Not the most compact solution, but then again writing Befunge code without whitespace is pretty difficult.

At the very beginning, it compares a space character with 0. If it's greater, it goes to the bottom row. If it isn't, which is what happens when you replace space with nothing, it stays on the first row.

Comment: What do the `,`s do?

Comment: @programmer5000 Each prints one character.

Comment: A tip for printing a large number of characters up until you reach a 0 is to do `>:#,_` which could save you a lot of bytes

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 36 bytes

```
J
"Programming Puzzles" "Code\40Golf
```

Try it online: [with](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J%0A%22Programming+Puzzles%22+%22Code%5C40Golf&debug=0) or [without](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J%22ProgrammingPuzzles%22%22Code%5C40Golf&debug=0) whitespace characters

That's a nice challenge for Pyth.

In the above code the newline prints `Programming Puzzles` and the space suppresses the output of `Code Golf`. `J` only assigns the first string to the variable `J`, but doesn't print anything.

After removing the newline and the spaces, the first string doesn't get printed (only assigned), but the second string gets printed implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 46 bytes

```
puts' '[0]?'Programming Puzzles':"Code\40Golf"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 53 bytes [non-competing]

**Holy crap I did it**

```
48*# 1+-?"Programming Puzzles"@19%"Code"1#!-"Golf"@9|
```

So the issue with Braingolf is that the only conditional it has is an "is the last number on the stack greater than 0?" check, which makes this kinda challenge a little tricky, but I persevered and here it is!

Non-competing because the language was created after the date of the challenge

Explanation:
Whitespace version:

```
48*                                                    Push the int literals 4 and 8 to the stack, then multiply them together, consuming both and adding the result to the stack (32)
   #<space>                                            Add the charcode of the literal char <space> to the stack, which also happens to be 32
     1+                                                Push int literal 1 to the stack, then add together the last 2 elements of the stack (1 and 32)
       -                                               Subtract the last 2 elements of the stack from each other (33 - 32)
        ?                                              Check if the last element on the stack is greater than 0, 33-32 is 1, so it is (this also consumes the checked number from the stack)
         "Programming Puzzles"                         Add the charcodes for the string "Programming Puzzles" to the stack
                              @19                      Print the last 19 elements of the stack as chars
                                 %                     Else, nothing after this will run, as the ? returned true
                                  "Code"               Push the charcodes for the string "Code" to the stack
                                        1#!-           Push the literal int 1 and the charcode for the character '!' (33) to the stack, then subtract one from the other (33 - 1 = 32, the charcode for a space)
                                            "Golf"     Push the charcodes for the string "Golf" to the stack
                                                  @9   Print the last 9 elements of the stack as characters
                                                    |  End if-else, at this point Braingolf would normally output the last element of the stack, as there is no semicolon in the program, however the stack is empty, so it doesn't.
```

No whitespace version (only the important part):

```
48*        Same as last time, push 4 and 8 to the stack, then multiply them to make 32
   #1      This time add the charcode for the character '1' to the stack (which is 49)
     +     Add the last 2 elements of the stack together (32 + 49 = 81)
      -    Subtract the last 2 elements of the stack from each other, however there is only 1 element in the stack (81) so subtract it from itself, 0
       ?   Is the last (only) element in the stack greater than 0? (no, it is 0)
           At this point the code skips every character up until the % else, and then runs from there to the end.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 51 bytes

```
]@,k9"Code"*84"Golf";
["selzzuP gnimmargorP">:#,_@;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#@x/roJNtqeScn5KqpGVhouSen5OmZM0VrVScmlNVVRqgkJ6XmZubWJSeXxSgZGelrBPvYP3/PwA)

The main idea here is to use the "turn right" operator (`]`) to check if there is a line below the first one. If there is, we print `selzzuP gnimmargorP` backwards. If the newline is removed, we turn right twice to go backwards on the top row. we use the `;`s to skip the "Programming Puzzles" code and print `Code Golf`.

I have other ideas about how to golf this whole thing (having to do with the fact that `ProgrammingPuzzles` is exactly twice as long as `Code Golf`) but I thought I would post a simple version first, considering my other one is in progress.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>67</s> 65 bytes

Even if it's longer than the one by @nimi, here's another Haskell solution, that works by abusing the `[]` Monad:

```hs
λ putStr$[s|s<-[" ">>"Programming Puzzles","Code\32Golf"],s/=""]!!0

  Programming Puzzles
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyflfraus4OPo5x7q6O6q4BwQoKCsW8uVZhvzv6C0JLikSCW6uKbYRjdaSUHJzk4poCg/vSgxNzczL10hoLSqKie1WElHyTk/JTXG2Mg9PydNKVanWN9WSSlWUdHgf25iZp6CrULafwA)

```hs
λ putStr$[s|s<-["">>"Programming Puzzles","Code\32Golf"],s/=""]!!0

  Code Golf
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyflfraus4OPo5x7q6O6q4BwQoKCsW8uVZhvzv6C0JLikSCW6uKbYRjdaScnOTimgKD@9KDE3NzMvPaC0qiontVhJR8k5PyU1xtjIPT8nTSlWp1jfVkkpVlHR4H9uYmaegq1C2n8A)

Thanks @Laikoni for golfing off 2 bytes!

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 56 bytes

```
INy,x:" ",Ix,,O"Programming Puzzles",INx,,O"Code\40Golf"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/9/Tr1KnwkpJQUnHs0JHx18poCg/vSgxNzczL10hoLSqKie1GCjlB5Zzzk9JjTExcM/PSVP6/x8A)

Uses a very similar technique to a lot of answers, and has the pseudocode of

```
x = ' '
if x:
    print('Programming Puzzles')
else:
    print('Code Golf')
```

By removing all whitespace, we make `x` equal to the empty string, which is falsey in Add++. Therefore, we output `Code Golf` instead of `Programming Puzzles`. The space in `Code Golf` is simply the octal value \$40_8 = 32_{10}\$. The only unusual part is the preceding `INy,`. With this, we are able to put all our code on one line, as this is a **compound** statement. Without this, the programming, with whitespace, would look something like this:

```
x:" "
Ix,O"Programming Puzzles"
INx,O"Code\40Golf"
```

But, when you remove the whitespace from this, we cause syntax errors, as outside of compound statements, Add++ has no other line terminator than a newline.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ahead](https://github.com/ajc2/ahead), 44 bytes

```
j ~"floG"32"edoC"~"selzzuP gnimmargorP"j~WW@
```

The first space is what's actually important. `j` will "jump over" the next cell in the head's direction; if the space is there it will be jumped over and the head will land on the first `~`, causing it to skip the section that pushes `Code Golf`. When the spaces are removed, the `~` will be jumped over and the first section will be entered instead.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8xITUz5/z9LoU4pLSffXcnYSCk1Jd9ZqU6pODWnqqo0QCE9LzM3N7EoPb8oQCmrLjzc4f9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Keg](https://github.com/JonoCode9374/Keg), <s>35</s> 30 bytes

```
‘∂⬭⑥⑷‘¶C≬;Puzz0ɧ;¶\ #ø¶[*;Golf
```

Without spaces:

```
‘∂⬭⑥⑷‘¶C≬;Puzz0ɧ;¶\#ø¶[*;Golf
```

### Explained

```
‘∂⬭⑥⑷‘¶C≬;Puzz0ɧ;¶\ #ø¶[*;Golf
‘∂⬭⑥⑷‘              #Push the string "Program"
       ¶C≬;Puzz0ɧ;¶     #Push the string "ing Puzzles"
                   \        #Escape the space and implicitly print

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

‘∂⬭⑥⑷‘¶C≬;Puzz0ɧ;¶\#ø¶[*;Golf
‘∂⬭⑥⑷‘¶C≬;Puzz0ɧ;¶\#        #Everything as before, but this time:
                     ø      #Empty the stack
                      ¶[*;Golf  #Push the string "Code Golf" and print
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATgAx/9rZWf//@KAmOKIguKsreKRpeKRt@KAmMK2Q@KJrDtQdXp6MMmnO8K2XCAjw7jCtlsqO0dvbGb//w)

### Answer History

#### 35 bytes

```
`∂⬭;⑥⑷;`¶C≬;Puzz0ɧ;¶+\ #__¶[*;Golf¶
```

Real shifty string compression going on here!
[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATkAxv9rZWf//2DiiILirK074pGl4pG3O2DCtkPiiaw7UHV6ejDJpzvCtitcICNfX8K2Wyo7R29sZsK2//8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 56 bytes

```lua
print((#' '>#'')and'Programming Puzzles'or'Code\32Golf')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDQ1ldQd1OWV1dMzEvRT2gKD@9KDE3NzMvXSGgtKoqJ7VYPb9I3Tk/JTXG2Mg9PydNXfP/fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 49 bytes

```sh
<<<${${:-ProgrammingPuzzles}/*gP*/$'Code\40Golf'}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P/fxsZGpVql2ko3oCg/vSgxNzczLz2gtKoqJ7W4Vl8rPUBLX0XdOT8lNcbEwD0/J029FqsOBfxaAA)

With spaces (in fact, only one added):

```sh
<<<${${:-Programming Puzzles}/*gP*/$'Code\40Golf'}
```

Uses `${    /match/replacement}`, and executes it on any string containing `gP`.

Answer (score 1):

## [yash](https://yash.osdn.jp), 50 bytes

This is POSIX-compatible.

```sh
echo Programming Puzzles||echo${IFS}Code${IFS}Golf
```

### How it works

Like @NahuelFouilleul but using `IFS` variable instead.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##q0wszvj/PzU5I18hoCg/vSgxNzczL10hoLSqKie1uKYGJKNS7ekWXOucn5IKYbnn56T9/w8A)

[Tryitonline!](https://tio.run/##q0wszvj/PzU5Iz@gKD@9KDE3NzMvPaC0qiontbimBiSuUu3pFlzrnJ@SCmG55@ek/f8PAA)

Answer (score 0):

### Ruby, 56 bytes

```
puts"Code\x20Golf"if(" "=="")#
puts"Programming Puzzles"
```

The second string literal should contain a tab.

Comment: You can save a fair number of bytes if you change `!(" ">"    ")` to `" "==""`. That should bring it to 56 bytes, by my count.

Answer (score 0):

## Microscript II, 45 bytes

```
" "("Programming Puzzles"ph)"Code"p32Kp"Golf"
```

Or, which is one byte longer:

```
' s#("Programming Puzzles"ph)"Code"p32Kp"Golf"
```

Answer (score 0):

## Microscript, 48 bytes

```
' d32{"floG"z32s"edoC"ah}"selzzuP gnimmargorP"ah
```

Or, which is the same length:

```
" "#{o"selzzuP gnimmargorP"ah}"floG"z32s"edoC"ah
```

Or:

```
' s#{o"selzzuP gnimmargorP"ah}"floG"z32s"edoC"ah
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 44 bytes

```
" "?"Programming Puzzles":"Code"48*"Golf"|&@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fSUHJXimgKD@9KDE3FyioEFBaVZWTWqxkpeScn5KqZGKhpeQOVKlUo@bw/z8A)

With whitespace removed:

```
""?"ProgrammingPuzzles":"Code"48*"Golf"|&@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fScleKaAoP70oMTcXKBZQWlWVk1qsZKXknJ@SqmRioaXkDlSnVKPm8P8/AA)

### Explanation

With whitespace:

```
" "                         push a space character
   ?                        if the last item on the stack > 0...
    "..."                   ...push the string "Programming Puzzles"
         :                  else...
          "..."             ...push the string "Code" and...
               48*          ...push 4 and 8 and multiply them and...
                  "..."     ...push the string "Golf"
                       |    end the conditional
                        &@  print all the characters on the stack
```

Without whitespace:

```
""                          push nothing
  ?                         if the last item on the stack > 0...
   "..."                    ...push the string "ProgrammingPuzzles"
        :                   else...
         "..."              ...push the string "Code" and...
              48*           ...push 4 and 8 and multiply them and...
                 "..."      ...push the string "Golf"
                      |     end the conditional
                       &@   print all the characters on the stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 37 bytes

```
"Programming Puzzles"  "Code0Golf"R0s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P9fKaAoP70oMTc3My9dIaC0qiontVhJQUHJOT8l1cA9PydNKcig@P9/AA)

#### Explanation

Comment abuse.

Anything following two spaces in Pip is a comment.* So with the spaces, this is just the string expression `"Programming Puzzles"`, which is autoprinted. Without the spaces, the first expression doesn't do anything, and we instead autoprint `"Code0Golf"R0s`, which replaces the `0` in `Code0Golf` with a space.

My original idea, `' ?"Programming Puzzles""Code0Golf"R0s` (fun with character literals), was 1 byte longer.

<sub>* Spaces at the beginning of a line don't count.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

## Petit Computer BASIC, 40 bytes

```
?"Code","Golf"'
CLS?"Programming Puzzles
```

The original program prints `Code Golf` and then clears the screen and prints `Programming Puzzles`.
When whitespace is removed it becomes `?"Code","Golf"'CLS?"Programming Puzzles` (`'` starts a comment), so only `Code Golf` is printed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), filename: <s>47</s> 43 bytes.

```
  .zAaGolf.-Code.p.d.aProgramming Puzzles.p
```

### What it does

Branches with first two spaces.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVh7V9rKFv@/n2JII5mQhGQQFIlRKXgt5yhFa11WQFcgQcGQcJKgaOB89d49kyAQeruua2lmfvs5@zEPn4OnX58/l@0Ds7/ft3uFQWG3bO1re3v9kqXtlQY9c6BZWqFY0kolUvoU2CFS7Kk@HZvBM9K0QkG3ZxPPD9F57aF6fm7UdBy@TWz0aId9zx1ks2zW98Zj07XEI9WyX1R36jiocJQl2Wwi3KpefzU4Hid8SJksFTCSyEf0I1UW8UBZcEuzP5qN24fv13WjoGm7S7D17Xvj9vznQ@3b1dVp7dogehtxfPSl@v3rw83p1ffGt2ZFeltwyEBvqJvNslV5aOIFw1k8k77EInf/Q8IeTx0ztFHwxPi9SQjDV8@3gokzDLNZ0xmaAVIekcBHROL4E24hGAL9Ctls88f5ee2iblSYDUztWXrwNByEOhsjypcAdv/JQ/xnkVom1HIGDBU8xzrKQuhfTAdxGTQwncDm5vN1GlPNpGfzwLaQEKgz9U3VA/jzrgpM4TvqUiHGBTxL0T4WsQdJqLpIeQmnZB76SKkFqNPWlIMuEtodN9cV5o@@PUH5WLl6X9zj1ahS1fme3tTVjsvmLTB3n893XFXVe1V9EU/b91QPIQVenah6uA6WtW2MEMKrXgrcP9jGCAFpN81Y3saIVuLVYZpxdxs7AL6HNAaW@ylsb38bIwSEg/T6drcxQsDFlzTj3jZGNIjYIO22to0RDSJmp3082MYIKfKqnzZd2MYIAenXNOP@NkYK4M8szVjexkgBfHxLMx5sY6QA/rynk6D9BgN3zPSiS9sYIRDbMG25uI0RDdwZp@O9v40RDdyx0qbL21gR0i@lMXBRSWG7wJdJY@A1n8bAmR2KLYQ57pvJdmGJSVOyflWjM9qUM92C/juj0h2c74gd3HHp33yuI/JqZ7dT6BAVuAI1n4NunW32d8XR@Uyktl9nb@@m1VUzUVPvOaBwob9Bs6tI1dX2fUKlJc6ryFI3dCguEhLz7fsTuQt2wQPcjofgQuEEUReeEp4YR/kckJhnsXVYz4S5yasyRXvgAqQ4glkmCmBUVSd67xLQmE0@AQUfjNYHo6XWl4wbbEtKEoeKr/NRbO4EUdWwxTFuVF0iYZWFls80gdJx20h57@Ysqi301xBYEotPN16sykgmsE1YTuPFmbHUArytXH6ozDPfwsvUnpvE4ytEpl6FuMyS5LLIruIWx@cs0cR@Y1diT5Ks/05QQMujYy0h6nCAHbNnO4bBdQgnRmwluD3x3OFDP3gZ2H44ljL8jtKl3B2CRV19jHloPXYiIncWlNTCHZLQzHWXgmkPczQhnEylj2HMVbgTTmZmxUVicJP/T8x1Xu35tvnMJpC3KuYcz5sg1wvR2Az7T0P3kQNWYblcCYtqDxOR@aawiZLMMmymxRMeJv8sJztsQtmgGVkjCgPPT2IFHum6GAn6R5cKC0EUf/2nWb04NQSE8u9V88xzBnml5ll2fpK38mbL9x59czwG91Br@v7u2EF@InyqfWtenzavDUH4hCf@0A0HcNYzRXxC4uavfaT0RTjNfwV@3xC@nJ41mhFkTgps2xIDH25ZmA0Xg6nbD4eei1q4Lkbf28/y31jsGnUdhl1JWtFPsRj5djj1XZSRgGdF@WtFAfyIrCh/ryhU3YpwvUGgJhWyRr7FV2J0ZQAXc0NR9IT5asUzxTUxYutHtRV6hq/kuw/dcIt0hq59pB3zWkVZc@xrbIAnOquee1aaEhQRx4kbEIqhbfM/qPmpa6zZruKLpUcXcw4yDfGnN9VhiNZMT2Dpr09Dx8YZCKnorUcSJhGA8/kU3wJtRXBxQ76R67Ij0iwywejGAB7dMRzbfQyf8I2o03prwHW3cWg4ujjFuG7AWoLQxzdyQ5JkIor/cmxd3HFdKpYrxZK4WBkZgvUWPtsw/IAv5Jp8J/8UowuDyz9UUBO6xkSW3R@O4foJi7UfbR@@k2nI6TUDxPU78IH6Qkse3C3uH9ay2dphqSyyPtQBq/3L3Rfbu6UuD1vInVEsKrVEOG5VYMHlWIwUISA1w9gtiFHMAi@DcOhO7QWNOGWtHRbLwHNU2hcpFBtfmY01iz8N/FNENaVY1mn29Ba@y/1cW2t/Gf0Wvt4IQrAk3K4n6wVyMpJvxKhhaMziyGB1DOEf0bKVR4rSNW5oouis0WUg5KHL5qPuWuj9lWmIKGb9KeZoDawZfF01zbY3M3wpM1sZaEca4QzMLlmJ3BiXh5Q3kb1ZCb39Uejo90LvH25QKeaGsuFKuFzME/SusUEaA@kZigXBw6mFKX2N2MMmBDQu8b9ohbeweQzikkkjUblNIqKvdoycQZRCDpuHmpijOYPvWlD/SesbJR1zmywWj3KOCBUDZrj8DpwbeahGroLubB@uUcOXYQBqOFooNCnm8ejIOR7tOBVnZ1RhY5WNIUeLeIcFzwytC@UAb73U3szN@yInrJwbQCQ2uD727u231x@eXkZ8ZsUXBbiHwRlGn8CK7z6TeX8KI0tAAlIGheXhBveaFs6K9A245o7Nijk@NCMoXFbQz5KkS9LoENNNmBYthDwO/yiZwkDUf78MulzLdmx4JkOeoRWS7QkaRJIahyAukbgl2EnTYBolAn0Sb/pSPO8uBJ2eVPT/A3CT6iP2P4Qp7RBvTF/EAPpb4CqGVhEpzeIGw3yOJ/A6r8KTf2jJdjgc2/KkP5nKL8G7bsG7XlzPQfHP718UmkMHbrfFtQDTG3ZUprccdpcS5ubrM@hCpqEUSHG/WN7dK5aREJmSwWuL02Y9OTVMuBNwn/7v/Cdak@jQDwcJgAOfYySB1@CKBj8cCuL0YG7H42ReE4X5zPQfIQaNGUoyN/uEfv0X)

[Tryitonline!](https://tio.run/##jVh7V9rKFv@/n2JII5mQhGQQFIlRKXgt5yhFa11WQFcgQcGQcJKgaOB89d49kyAQeruua2lmfvs5@zEPn4OnX58/l@0Ds7/ft3uFQWG3bO1re3v9kqXtlQY9c6BZWqFY0kolUvoU2CFS7Kk@HZvBM9K0QkG3ZxPPD9F57aF6fm7UdBy@TWz0aId9zx1ks2zW98Zj07XEI9WyX1R36jiocJQl2Wwi3KpefzU4Hid8SJksFTCSyEf0I1UW8UBZcEuzP5qN24fv13WjoGm7S7D17Xvj9vznQ@3b1dVp7dogehtxfPSl@v3rw83p1ffGt2ZFeltwyEBvqJvNslV5aOIFw1k8k77EInf/Q8IeTx0ztFHwxPi9SQjDV8@3gokzDLNZ0xmaAVIekcBHROL4E24hGAL9Ctls88f5ee2iblSYDUztWXrwNByEOhsjypcAdv/JQ/xnkVom1HIGDBU8xzrKQuhfTAdxGTQwncDm5vN1GlPNpGfzwLaQEKgz9U3VA/jzrgpM4TvqUiHGBTxL0T4WsQdJqLpIeQmnZB76SKkFqNPWlIMuEtodN9cV5o@@PUH5WLl6X9zj1ahS1fme3tTVjsvmLTB3n893XFXVe1V9EU/b91QPIQVenah6uA6WtW2MEMKrXgrcP9jGCAFpN81Y3saIVuLVYZpxdxs7AL6HNAaW@ylsb38bIwSEg/T6drcxQsDFlzTj3jZGNIjYIO22to0RDSJmp3082MYIKfKqnzZd2MYIAenXNOP@NkYK4M8szVjexkgBfHxLMx5sY6QA/rynk6D9BgN3zPSiS9sYIRDbMG25uI0RDdwZp@O9v40RDdyx0qbL21gR0i@lMXBRSWG7wJdJY@A1n8bAmR2KLYQ57pvJdmGJSVOyflWjM9qUM92C/juj0h2c74gd3HHp33yuI/JqZ7dT6BAVuAI1n4NunW32d8XR@Uyktl9nb@@m1VUzUVPvOaBwob9Bs6tI1dX2fUKlJc6ryFI3dCguEhLz7fsTuQt2wQPcjofgQuEEUReeEp4YR/kckJhnsXVYz4S5yasyRXvgAqQ4glkmCmBUVSd67xLQmE0@AQUfjNYHo6XWl4wbbEtKEoeKr/NRbO4EUdWwxTFuVF0iYZWFls80gdJx20h57@Ysqi301xBYEotPN16sykgmsE1YTuPFmbHUArytXH6ozDPfwsvUnpvE4ytEpl6FuMyS5LLIruIWx@cs0cR@Y1diT5Ks/05QQMujYy0h6nCAHbNnO4bBdQgnRmwluD3x3OFDP3gZ2H44ljL8jtKl3B2CRV19jHloPXYiIncWlNTCHZLQzHWXgmkPczQhnEylj2HMVbgTTmZmxUVicJP/T8x1Xu35tvnMJpC3KuYcz5sg1wvR2Az7T0P3kQNWYblcCYtqDxOR@aawiZLMMmymxRMeJv8sJztsQtmgGVkjCgPPT2IFHum6GAn6R5cKC0EUf/2nWb04NYT8e9U885xBXql5lp2f5K282fK9R98cj8G51vT93bGD/ET4VPvWvD5tXhuC8AlP/KEbDuCgZ1r4hMTNX/tI6YtwlP8K/L4hfDk9azQjSJsU2LYlBj5csTAbLgZTtx8OPRe1cF2Mvref5b@x2DXqOgy7krSin2Ix8u1w6rsoIwHPivLXigL4EVlR/l5RqLoV4XqDQE0qZI18i6/E6MoALuaGougJ89WKZ4prYsTWj2or9AxfyXcfuuEK6Qxd@0g75rWKsubY19gAT3RWOvesLiWoII4TNyAUQ9vmf1DzU9dYs13FF0uPLuYcpBniT6@pwxCtmZ7A0l@fho6NMxBS0VuPJEwiAOfzKb4F2org4oZ8I9dlR6RZZILRjQE8umM4tvsYPuEbUafF1oC7buPQcHRxinHdgLUEoY9v5IYkyUQU/@XYurjjulQsV4olcbEyMgTrLXy2YfgBX8g1@U7@KUYXBpd/qKAmtIyJLLs/HMPdExZrP9o@fCfTkNNrBojrd@AD9YXWO7hb3D@sZbO1w1JZZE2oA1b7l7svtndLXR72jzujWFRqiXDcp8CCy7EYKUJAaoaxWxCjmAWeBeHQndoLGnHKWjssloHnqLQvUig2vjIbaxZ/GviniGpKsazT7OktfJf7ubbW/jL6LXy9EYRgSbhdT9YL5GQk34hRw9CYxZHB6hjCP6JlK48UpWvc0ETRWaPLQMhDl81H3bXQ@yvTEFHM@lPM0RpYM/i6apptb2b4Uma2MtCONMIZmF2yErkxLg8pbyJ7sxJ6@6PQ0e@F3j/coFLMDWXDlXC5mCfoXWODNAbSMxQLgldTC1P6GrGHTQhoXOJ/0QpvYfMYxCWTRqJym0REX@0YOYMohRw2DzUxR3MG37Wg/pPWN0o65jZZLB7lHBEqBsxw@R04NPJQjVwF3dk@3KGGL8MA1HC0UGhSzOPRkXM82nEqzs6owsYqG0OOFvEOC54ZWhfKAR56qb2Zm/dFTlg5N4BIbHB97N3bD68/vLuM@MCKbwlwCYMDjL5/Fd99JvP@FEaWgASkDArLkw0uNS2cFekDcM0dmxVzfGJGULisoJ8lSZek0SGmmzAtWgh5HP5RMoWBqP9@GXS5lu3Y8EaGPEMrJNsTNIgkNQ5BXCJxS7CTpsE0SgT6JN70pXjeXQg6PanoPwfgGtVH7B8IU9oh3pg@hwH0t8BVDK0iUprFDYb5HE/gaV6F9/7Qku1wOLblSX8ylV@Cd92CR724noPinx@/KDSHDlxti2sBptfrqEyvOOwiJczN12fQhUxDKZDifrG8u1csIyEyJYPXFqfNenJqmHAh4D793/lPtCbRoR8OEgAHPsdIAq/B/Qx@OBTE6cHcjsfJvCYK85npP0IMGjOUZG72Cf36Lw)

Comment: Note that it's `Programming Puzzles`, with an `s` at the end